# IE doesn't support height=auto for images, what should I use?

Tags: css, image, cross-browser

I have some images with height=auto because sometimes they are different heights whereas they are always the same width.  It works in every browser but I.E., is there something similar I can use?

Comment: What does `height=auto` do? If you don't specify a height it will use whatever the actual height value of the image is.

Comment: It causes the image to have a height of 1 in IE. Works just fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was to add the typical IE fix :(

css:

```
height:auto !important;
```

Comment: had to add a specific max-height

Comment: IE doesn't know about max-height. IE does not allow important to be set programaticaly `element.style.height="auto !important"` = invalid argument.

Answer (score 58):

I found that adding `min-height:1px` solves the issue. Not sure why, but, worked for me.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me in ie11 in a flex container, besides leaving out. Thank you.

Comment: Leave it to Michalsoft to force users to do that

Comment: 13 years in the business and I still don't know why either.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I just had a client on IE 11 say what a mess the site was. I forgot my own answer. 24 years in business and I am glad browsers are so much more uniform these days.

Answer (score 12):

Just leave

```
height=auto
```

out. If it's not given it's "auto" by default...

Answer (score 3):

i've tried all the solutions posted, and the only one that works is

```
height=100%
```

Comment: This can have the unintended consequence of stretching the image.

Answer (score 1):

Use height: auto together with width: auto and it is going to work in IE. If you specify only one of them, IE gets upset.

```
height: auto;
width: auto;
```

Comment: It will only choose the latter. In this case, causing the width to take precedence over the height.

Comment: This doesn't work in I.E. 10. When I removed width:auto; and kept height:auto; it began displaying the object again. Otherwise the image wouldn't appear with both on auto.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an IE issue when using images with `height=auto` within flex containers.

For me personally, the issue was caused due to the image being placed within nested flex containers. I was able to remove the parent flex container and the issue was resolved for me.

There are a few more work around solutions that people have mentioned in the page below:
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/75

Answer (score 1):

You can do `width="100%"` and `max-width="100px"` or whatever width you want and then simply `height="auto"`. This worked for me.

BTW you may need `min-width` width your wanted width too if your parent element doesn't have the width that you want for your image.

Answer (score 0):

For Edge browser you can use max-height, which will also work for other browsers

```
max-height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixes with min-height and !important didn't work for me.
My img was in a flex container.
I then tried putting the img inside another, wrapping div and then height:auto worked.

Answer (score -1):

In "IE9 compatibility view - IE7 Standard Document mode" leaving off height=auto may not solve the problem.  Try adding conditional CSS and in your special css file for IE ("ie.css") add a line that assigns the appropriate min-height to your affected class/element.

for example:

.IE7 .[*css element*] {min-height: xxxpx;}

Where xxx equals the necessary image height.

Comment: That assumes other code at the top of the page... see http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie7-ie8-css-hacks/

Answer (score -3):

height: initial; will work instead of using height: auto; in chrome and ie.