# Images don't work in IE10&11

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I embed images from Facebook links. While it works perfectly in Firefox, IE doesn't want to work with it. The div and the image tags are both generated in the HTML, but the image is absent. I've tried to look for most common IE bugs with images, but never found anything relevant.

Here's the link: http://spotbc.com/example.php

Comment: Same here ok in IE10 and IE11 -> empty cache? proxy settings?

Comment: Your html is pretty bad. you have no `"` around your img src attributes, anywhere.

Comment: I tried it on different machines, with the same result. I actually see doublequotes around img src atributes, so I don't get the point. Images are actually appearing as a thin 1px wide line.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if you have no specific system/network/proxy settings especially for IE. We can see your image fine here. Try empty/close your browser cache (try on a different machine if it helps).

Though you could leave out quotes for the src attribute of an img tag in an [HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes) document it is not consistent with the rest of your code. Review your generated HTML structure for best results. `</br>` is also no valid HTML.

Comment: Hm, the problem is actually the "height" attribute. When I put an integer, it works as expected, but the "auto" mode doesn't manage to give it a size, so images are 1px high. Hm.

Comment: Well, the problem is that sometimes IE doesn't support the "auto" attribute for size. I just omit that and it works as expected. Answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673356/ie-doesnt-support-height-auto-for-images-what-should-i-use

Comment: ok so you got it sorted - good to know - that is weird though because I could see your images displayed in IE yesterday and so jumpingcode ...

Comment: Indeed. I had already tried it on different machines before posting, so it's even more weird. Maybe some kind of IE parameters we adopt in the enterprise, a little nothing like "html transformation" or xss filter.