# IE11 flexbox column heights issue

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a row of `li`s each containing an `img` then a `p`.

The `p`s need to have equal heights.

[This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurtfrobe/8d2ah8tv/8/) works fine except in IE11 where the `p`s somehow get extra height.

**Update:** It seems the extra height is coming from the scaled down image. I've read that IE11 struggles with `height: auto` and flexbox. Still haven't solved it yet though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It appears that IE11 doesn't recognize `height: auto` on images. My answer here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40044724/3597276

Comment: FYI, the 'flex' tag refers to the programming framework for Flash, not the CSS flexbox model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it with a combination of this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/leonderijke/pen/nxFhH) and [this article](http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios).

The trick was to give the image container a `height`, but still keep it responsive.